# Add AD entries using ldapadd failing with "unwilling to perform"

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to add entries to an Active Directory using ldapadd. Here's my ldif file:

```
DN: CN=John_Smith,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=net
objectClass: user 
CN: John_Smith
sn: John 
givenName: Smith 
displayName: John_Smith 
sAMAccountName: jsmith 
userPrincipalName: jsmith@example.net
```

I'm aware that if you attempt to modify/update or add a user password, Active Directory will require you to have a SSL connection to the server. However, this fails without me trying to update the user password. Here's the response:

```
adding new entry "CN=John_Smith,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=net"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: 00002035: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D64, comment: Operation not allowed through GC port, data 0, v2580
```

This active directory was deployed using AWS Directory Service wizard.

Comment: don't use the general catalog port to add users

Comment: @natxoasenjo Thanks! I tried using port 389 and got passed this issue. However, now I'm getting a `INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS` error, even though I'm using the admin user. Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: Also my admin entry contains this: `memberOf: CN=Admins,OU=Users,OU=example,DC=example,DC=net`

Comment: in AD out of the box there is a 'Domain Admins' group per domain, not 'Admins'. You can create an 'Admins' group, that is not a problem, but you need to assign that group the necessary rights. Consult your AD administrator to verify that Admins group has the necessary rights to add user in the users container you are trying to use

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the global catalogue port for user creation. If your server requires a SSL connection, use the ldaps port which defaults to to `636`.

Also, please ensure the new password complies with your password complexity policy and password history policy. The `unwilling to perform` error message is a common result of a conflict with the password policy.

Answer (score 1):

As @natxoasenjo points out, you shouldn't use the global catalog port to add users. I used port 389 and got past this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me to add a group with our local win2012 based directory.  OU path obscured, of course.

```
DN: CN=testunixgrp,OU=Unix Groups,OU=Groups,blah,blah,blah
cn: testunixgrp
name: testunixgrp
distinguishedName: CN=testgrp,OU=Unix Groups,OU=Groups,blah,blah,blah
sAMAccountName: testunixgrp
gidNumber: 123456
instanceType: 4
objectClass: top
objectClass: group
```